# Simplifying a differentiation and integration

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have this equation, $g(c)=x(t)=\dfrac{\exp(z(t))}{\int_a^b \exp(z(s))\,\text{d}s}$ where $z(t)=b(t)^Tc + b(t)^Tau$, I need to find g'(c). So far I got,

$g(c)=x(t)=\dfrac{\exp(z(t))}{\int_a^b \exp(z(s))\,\text{d}s}$

So, $g'(c)=\dfrac{{[\int_a^b \exp(z(s))\,\text{d}s}]\exp(z(t))z'(t)-\exp(z(t))\int_a^b \exp(z(s))z'(s)\,\text{d}s}{[\int_a^b \exp(z(s))\,\text{d}s]^2}$
$g'(c)=\dfrac{{[\int_a^b \exp(z(s))\,\text{d}s}]\exp(z(t))b(t)^T-\exp(z(t))\int_a^b \exp(z(s))b(s)^T\,\text{d}s}{[\int_a^b \exp(z(s))\,\text{d}s]^2}$

Is there anything I have done wrong here? If not, is it possible to do any more simplification?

Answer (score 1):

I would see it the same as you. Slight simplification could be:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial x(t,c)}{\partial c}&=\exp(z(t))\frac{\left[\int_a^b \exp(z(s))\,\text{d}s\right]b^{\text{T}}(t)-\int_a^b \exp(z(s))b^{\text{T}}(s)\,\text{d}s}{\left[\int_a^b \exp(z(s))\,\text{d}s\right]^2}\nonumber \\&=x(t)\frac{\left[\int_a^b \exp(z(s))\,\text{d}s\right]b^{\text{T}}(t)-\int_a^b \exp(z(s))b^{\text{T}}(s)\,\text{d}s}{\int_a^b \exp(z(s))\,\text{d}s}
\end{align}
I would also change notation, there is twice $b$ with different meaning.